# How to make the buttons align bottom without any space below the buttons

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

How to align the buttons bottom of the screen.In the layout i have header below scrollview which contains many textviews and edittext and last is the 2 buttons that i want to place it bottom without any space be[image]see at the bottom as i am able to align it bottom but ther is a small space between buttton and the screentween layout and buttons...

Comment: @Girish -- paste your code so we can understand your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in reverse way...
Open -Relative Layout 
   * Button1 - parent bottom true
   * Button2 - Parent bottom true, Right of Button1, top align Button1, Bottom align Button1
   * Header  - Parent top true
   * Scroll view - Below Header and Above Button1
close - Relative Layout

Comment: More number of layouts you consume, more the memory you eat up. So, better go for one layout,rather than placing buttons in linear layout. If no other alternative, we can run for next layout. This can be solved as mentioned above, with one layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:layout_martin="0dp"` to set the margin to zero, but with some Views this isn't enough as the 9Patch being used for the View background has a margin in it as well. In that case you need to both set the margin to zero, and use a different background 9patch.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1):

make them in separate layout and and arrange at parent bottom

```
<LinearLayout            
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/save_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="save"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"        
         android:textStyle="bold"           
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
         android:layout_height="35dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/cancel_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="35dp"      
         android:text="cancel"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"       
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```